# Capacitor and Ionic native status-bar

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic4, ionic-native, capacitor

I have created the Ionic 4 Capacitor app. It shows this by default and no Cordova plugin.

*package.json*

```
   "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
   "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
```

*app.component.ts*

```
 async initializeApp(): Promise<void> {
    await this.platform.ready();

    this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.splashScreen.hide();

  }
```

But Capacitor doc says where it is [not compatible with it](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/status-bar#capacitor). Do I need to remove this native plugin and use Capacitor implementation or since there is no Cordova here will this no issue?

Comment: I've didn't go much through capacitor, but you could install the stusbar capacitor plugin since for sure since they made this plugin also in capacitor, it could reflect better peformance or any other thing with capacitor, else they could have not made this plugin also for capacitor and could have just used cordova plugin without mention, so i think its better to go through capacitor plugin..

Comment: @MostafaHarb Why they have given this by default? Yes. I need to ask this from the Ionic team and of course, I have done that too. And it shows Splash and Status bar without issue on Native build too. They have mentioned only about Cordova plugins here: https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/known-incompatible-plugins

Comment: There are 2 ways to add capacitor to you app, the first is to create ionic project normally and then after created you add capacitor, and the second is to create the project as capacitor directly, so they made the project be created in same structure (the only difference will be adding file of cordova reference. So the app.component.ts and others at project creation will be the same, and will work normally if project was cordova or capacitor, but at this point, you could install capacitor made plugins as i said in previous comment.

Comment: @MostafaHarb This is a Capacitor project. The problem here is the bug on the default template. You can see that on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're working on updating the starter app templates - soon, they'll default to Capacitor APIs.

I think those two actually do work with Cap, but as Ricardo wrote, our recommendation would be to use the Capacitor APIs.

Here's what I'm using in one of our [sample apps](https://github.com/ionic-team/photo-gallery-capacitor-ng):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { SplashScreen } = Plugins;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    /* To make sure we provide the fastest app loading experience 
       for our users, hide the splash screen automatically 
       when the app is ready to be used:

        https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/splash-screen#hiding-the-splash-screen
    */
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is super confusing now. I hope you'll fix this issue soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

capacitor states that is not compatible with the cordova plugin because it delivers their own [cordova-plugin-statusbar (not needed, Capacitor has its own)](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/known-incompatible-plugins)
Therefore I advise you should be using the one from capacitor.

Something similar to this:

```
const { SplashScreen, StatusBar } = Plugins;
try {
  await SplashScreen.hide();
  await StatusBar.setStyle({ style: StatusBarStyle.Light });
} catch (err) {
  console.log('This does not have influence on the browser', err);
}
```

Comment: Yes, my question was why they have given Native plugins with the Capacitor project if it is not compatible. That is a bug. It confirmed the Ionic team member on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around I could not found a solution.

But after playing around with Xcode, I discovered what could be a temporary Solution.

Your will have to change the status bar color using native code in Xcode....this was the only solution I could come with